# Generate a map + route with a polyline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-polyline

On the web I can only find bits or peaces of code that generate a map or only convert a polyline to an array of coordinates. But so far I'm unable to glue those peaces together in a working solution for me.

My situation:
From Strava I'm retrieving polylines containing the routes I have cycled.
For example this polyline below:

```
ixw|Huue_@n@cFdC`BpCg\pIiL_AwPjS}{@gMic@uDe_@mTeXoA{P{LuDcTcXeg@yP_\{]{a@kRbA_l@jMum@lCczAx`@Yzs@|Qld@x@`PlNxoBxo@bUfClAkNz[y@rCarApHa^qYkHec@ao@kNgsAuQo^h@wVtgBlM~b@da@ba@}hBrRij@uTy\uDmOkHed@aAea@zSsEtVfGpCgQa\ag@}w@{vBcFqF{WdDUyJcTcq@gIiy@yM_B~Bat@tAwF`OaCnOlOfUjEvd@b^~JzTnb@lc@tz@j^jKrPpEcMp^b]hM}t@n}@_hAfa@ciCya@qZaVqt@_R}Wn{@o_C`KcAzLrRbZwKl@e{@`UyXpBwm@nIgd@zEeVtPgUb@iRvEaKpPtNf`@|FrNqdBmEscAdH{ToRwhBdVcEgQuqBvR|WxYxr@bG|o@qGjs@ah@h_AzD`hAiOpnByg@oG`Xd[`OjZsBlg@sIrRo`@wd@uQUyXnKcCdo@yTrXfA~RmBnf@gBf@lB`jBqSbo@gJnBsJ~Skb@|aBoCxWqR`j@d^|Ss|@feAqFbQaIz{@uV}TeV{`@uhA}j@aa@}l@qc@s^{UmFgPwNoMlB{BpFwF|dBqOpM_UrpAh]mEnCjcAoj@qYgLhcBpL|aAwEfc@xSr[bb@d^}S|JuOnYkAt~@`Rt`@vE`z@xGhW|b@~l@lWfHiIrt@|D|mAyIhr@oEf{AkOzbAkx@blBkK{PyKeDqPkZmx@b~C
```

I understand in order to show this polyline (route) in a map I have to convert it to some coordinates.

How can I convert this polyline and show it on a google map?
Thanks!!

Comment: @Dr.Molle When I use the example in the question you provide I get the error "\u can only be followed by a Unicode character sequence"

Comment: Try to escape all backslashes in the encoded path with an additional backslash

Comment: This seems to work. Do you have an suggestion how to add these automatically when needed?

Comment: JS can't handle this string. I'm not sure how you "import" this string into your application, but you may e.g. store it as a value of a `<input/>` and read it from the input.

Comment: I receive the polylines from strava API via a JSON-P callback

Comment: The encoded polyline(as you've posted) isn't a valid string(it also wouldn't be valid JSON). When you really get the string you've posted via JSONP they(STRAVA) have a bug in the service and there is nothing you can do(at least nothing as long you receive the data via javascript directly).